# class BottleofWater () : def __int__(self, contenance, couleur, matiere) :

Tags: python

je veux créer une class BottleOfWater () et à l'intérieur une fonction avec pour argument contenant, couleur et liquide

Comment: write your question in English

Comment: And even if it were written in English, your question is totally unclear: "I want to create a class ... " and a piece of code, without any explanation about what doesn't work with it, can't really be considered a question;